# How to move fixes developed on branch to another

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

We currently have a `release` branch (from `master`) on which we are developing features and bugfixes. We've discovered that we need to release some of these fixes early and so need to extract them from the `release` branch and drop them onto `master`.

What's the easiest way of getting from

```
A--B--C master
       \
        D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K release
```

to

```
A--B--C--F--G--J master
       \
        D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K release
```

?

I could `cherry-pick` the merge commits from `release` onto `master` but will that cause headaches when `release` is eventually merged into `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

1. Create a new branch `hotfix` from current state of master. That would point to C
2. Cherry-pick commits (not merge requests) F, G and J into `hotfix`.
3. Open a merge request from `hotfix` to `master`

Comment: Does this really help over cherry-picking from release directly?  When you merge `release` into `master`, won't you still potentially get unneeded conflicts as F,G,and J are already in `master`?

Comment: F, G and J are not in master when you merge `hotfix`, that's the point of cherry-picking them into `hotfix` first. You can, of course, cherry-pick directly into `master` but that makes it slightly harder and riskier to undo the operation in case things break.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense about easier to undo the operation. I was thinking only about the future merge of `release` into `master`.